# How to return a custom object from a Spring Data JPA GROUP BY query

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, repository

I'm developing a Spring Boot application with Spring Data JPA. I'm using a custom JPQL query to group by some field and get the count. Following is my repository method.

```
@Query(value = "select count(v) as cnt, v.answer from Survey v group by v.answer")
public List<?> findSurveyCount();
```

It's working and result is obtained as follows:

```
[
  [1, "a1"],
  [2, "a2"]
]
```

I would like to get something like this:

```
[
  { "cnt":1, "answer":"a1" },
  { "cnt":2, "answer":"a2" }
]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 378, accepted):

## Solution for JPQL queries

This is supported for JPQL queries within the [JPA specification](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_05/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_constructor).

> **Step 1**: Declare a simple bean class

```
package com.path.to;

public class SurveyAnswerStatistics {
  private String answer;
  private Long   cnt;

  public SurveyAnswerStatistics(String answer, Long cnt) {
    this.answer = answer;
    this.count  = cnt;
  }
}
```

> **Step 2**: Return bean instances from the repository method

```
public interface SurveyRepository extends CrudRepository<Survey, Long> {
    @Query("""
            SELECT
             new com.path.to.SurveyAnswerStatistics(v.answer, COUNT(v))
            FROM
             Survey v
            GROUP BY v.answer""")
    List<SurveyAnswerStatistics> findSurveyCount();
}
```

#### *Important notes*

1. Make sure to provide the fully-qualified path to the bean class, including the package name. For example, if the bean class is called `MyBean` and it is in package `com.path.to`, the fully-qualified path to the bean will be `com.path.to.MyBean`. Simply providing `MyBean` will not work (unless the bean class is in the default package).
2. Make sure to call the bean class constructor using the `new` keyword. `SELECT new com.path.to.MyBean(...)` will work, whereas `SELECT com.path.to.MyBean(...)` will not.
3. Make sure to pass attributes in exactly the same order as that expected in the bean constructor. Attempting to pass attributes in a different order will lead to an exception.
4. Make sure the query is a valid JPA query, that is, it is not a native query. `@Query("SELECT ...")`, or `@Query(value = "SELECT ...")`, or `@Query(value = "SELECT ...", nativeQuery = false)` will work, whereas `@Query(value = "SELECT ...", nativeQuery = true)` will not work. This is because native queries are passed without modifications to the JPA provider, and are executed against the underlying RDBMS as such. Since `new` and `com.path.to.MyBean` are not valid SQL keywords, the RDBMS then throws an exception.

---

## Solution for native queries

As noted above, the `new ...` syntax is a JPA-supported mechanism and works with all JPA providers. However, if the query itself is not a JPA query, that is, it is a native query, the `new ...` syntax will not work as the query is passed on directly to the underlying RDBMS, which does not understand the `new` keyword since it is not part of the SQL standard.

In situations like these, bean classes need to be replaced with [Spring Data Projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) interfaces.

> **Step 1**: Declare a projection interface

```
package com.path.to;

public interface SurveyAnswerStatistics {
  String getAnswer();

  int getCnt();
}
```

> **Step 2**: Return projected properties from the query

```
public interface SurveyRepository extends CrudRepository<Survey, Long> {
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value =
          """
           SELECT
            v.answer AS answer, COUNT(v) AS cnt
           FROM
            Survey v
           GROUP BY v.answer""")
    List<SurveyAnswerStatistics> findSurveyCount();
}
```

Use the SQL `AS` keyword to map result fields to projection properties for unambiguous mapping.

Comment: It's not working, firing error : `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate class [SurveyAnswerReport] [select new SurveyAnswerReport(v.answer,count(v.id)) from com.furniturepool.domain.Survey v group by v.answer]
 at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750)
 at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
 at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEnti..........`

Comment: What is this `SurveyAnswerReport ` in your output.  I assume you replaced `SurveyAnswerStatistics ` with your own class `SurveyAnswerReport`. You need to specify the fully qualified class name.

Comment: The bean class must be fully qualified, that is, include the full package name.  Something like `com.domain.dto.SurveyAnswerReport`.

Comment: @manish Please post a link where more of this can be read. Thanks!

Comment: This is part of the [JPA specification](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_05/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_constructor).

Comment: Can you confirm the name of the class which extends the JPARepository in this case, is it called SurveyRepository or SurveyAnswerStatisticsRepository? Thanks

Comment: How would you use DATE() in such custom query? I need to group by DATE(created_date);

Comment: I got 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PersistentEntity must not be null!` when i try return custom type from my `JpaRepository` ? Is some configuration i missed ?

Comment: Don't omit the "new" keyword in the query, if you do you'll see a Hibernate exception "No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode"!   (Thanks @manish this was a big help)

Comment: i am trying to run below query. but it not working can anyone help here plz. 
@Query(value = "select new com.unilever.d2.integration.transaction.modal.coupons.OfferStatus(offerId, CASE WHEN (InventoryCount=0 or InventoryCount - ConsumptionCount > 0) and  ( StartDate is null or getdate() >  StartDate ) and ( EndDate  is null or getdate() < EndDate ) THEN 'false' else 'true' end) from OfferMaster where Brand= ?1 and Locale = ?2 and CampaignId = ?3")
 public List<?> getOffersStatus2(String brand, String locale, String campaignId);

Comment: @AwanishKumar, I have added some important considerations to the answer. Please review and make sure you are following the listed points. I suspect that you are trying to execute a native SQL query (because `CASE`, `WHEN`, `THEN` and `getDate()` are not valid JPQL keywords), which is why things are not working for you.

Comment: with native query i get: `Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy...`. What may be wrong ?

Comment: non native query did not work it throws an exception table cannot be mapped

Comment: native query did not work either. Exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: [bean]. Forgot to register a type adapter?

Comment: @manish: If we have more tables and we Join them in this query, We get token (tablename) exception.

Comment: @Android, can you ask it as a separate question, posting the code that is throwing the error, and error details?

Comment: Native query does not work for me to. It just returns 0 items, no exception though. If I test the same raw SQL in SQL prompts, it returns the dataset.

Comment: @manish will the Class Base Projection work instead of Projection Interface? Because at then end I need the result as DTO to transfer via REST api.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.dtos

Comment: While using native query exception says: nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class ...
Why this should be happed ?

Comment: @manish in my understanding the missed class Survey should be just simple POJO class, right?

Answer (score 29):

This SQL query  return List< Object[] > would.

*You can do it this way:*

```
 @RestController
 @RequestMapping("/survey")
 public class SurveyController {

   @Autowired
   private SurveyRepository surveyRepository;

     @RequestMapping(value = "/find", method =  RequestMethod.GET)
     public Map<Long,String> findSurvey(){
       List<Object[]> result = surveyRepository.findSurveyCount();
       Map<Long,String> map = null;
       if(result != null && !result.isEmpty()){
          map = new HashMap<Long,String>();
          for (Object[] object : result) {
            map.put(((Long)object[0]),object[1]);
          }
       }
     return map;
     }
 }
```

Comment: thanks for your response to this question. It was crisp and clear

Comment: @manish  Thanks you saved my night's sleep, your method worked like a charm!!!!!!!

Comment: Thank you... I prefer this solution over the accepted answers native-query solution to avoid a long list of projection interfaces.

Comment: This only works while comparing above answers.

Answer (score 23):

I know this is an old question and it has already been answered, but here's another approach:

```
@Query("select new map(count(v) as cnt, v.answer) from Survey v group by v.answer")
public List<?> findSurveyCount();
```

Comment: I like your answer because it doesn't force me to create a new class or interface. It worked for me.

Comment: Works fine but i prefer the usage of Map in the generics instead of ?, as Map will let us access them as key (0) and value (1)

Answer (score 6):

define a custom pojo class say sureveyQueryAnalytics and store the query returned value in your custom pojo class

```
@Query(value = "select new com.xxx.xxx.class.SureveyQueryAnalytics(s.answer, count(sv)) from Survey s group by s.answer")
List<SureveyQueryAnalytics> calculateSurveyCount();
```

Comment: The solution is better.Or use [the projection in the official document.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections)

Answer (score 4):

I do not like java type names in query strings and handle it with a specific constructor.
Spring JPA implicitly calls constructor with query result in HashMap parameter:

```
@Getter
public class SurveyAnswerStatistics {
  public static final String PROP_ANSWER = "answer";
  public static final String PROP_CNT = "cnt";

  private String answer;
  private Long   cnt;

  public SurveyAnswerStatistics(HashMap<String, Object> values) {
    this.answer = (String) values.get(PROP_ANSWER);
    this.count  = (Long) values.get(PROP_CNT);
  }
}

@Query("SELECT v.answer as "+PROP_ANSWER+", count(v) as "+PROP_CNT+" FROM  Survey v GROUP BY v.answer")
List<SurveyAnswerStatistics> findSurveyCount();
```

Code needs Lombok for resolving @Getter

Comment: @Getter is showing an error before running the code as its not for the object type

Comment: Lombok is needed. Just added a footnote to the code.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Constructor is not called. For me works only interface-based projection or class-based projection with `new`  in `@Query`. It would be great if class-based without `new` (with this constructor `HashMap<String, Object>`) worked. But I get `org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [package.MyClass]`.

Comment: seems that spring can't inject the Map object into the constructor because they're of different types. The repository return type is not Map<String, Object> so it cant invoke the apropriated converter. Found the post below which might help

https://www.bytestree.com/spring/spring-data-jpa-projections-5-ways-return-custom-object/

Answer (score 3):

```
@Repository
public interface ExpenseRepo extends JpaRepository<Expense,Long> {
    List<Expense> findByCategoryId(Long categoryId);

    @Query(value = "select category.name,SUM(expense.amount) from expense JOIN category ON expense.category_id=category.id GROUP BY expense.category_id",nativeQuery = true)
    List<?> getAmountByCategory();

}
```

The above code worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I used custom DTO (interface) to map a native query to - the most flexible approach and refactoring-safe.

The problem I had with this - that surprisingly, the order of fields in the interface and the columns in the query matters. I got it working by ordering interface getters alphabetically and then ordering the columns in the query the same way.

Answer (score 1):

**I just solved this problem :**

- Class-based Projections doesn't work with query native(`@Query(value = "SELECT ...", nativeQuery = true`)) so I recommend to define custom DTO using interface .
- Before using DTO should verify  the query syntatically correct or not

Answer (score 1):

Get data with column name and its values (in key-value pair) using JDBC:

```
/*Template class with a basic set of JDBC operations, allowing the use
  of named parameters rather than traditional '?' placeholders.
 
  This class delegates to a wrapped {@link #getJdbcOperations() JdbcTemplate}
  once the substitution from named parameters to JDBC style '?' placeholders is
  done at execution time. It also allows for expanding a {@link java.util.List}
  of values to the appropriate number of placeholders.
 
  The underlying {@link org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate} is
  exposed to allow for convenient access to the traditional
  {@link org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate} methods.*/


@Autowired
protected  NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbc;


@GetMapping("/showDataUsingQuery/{Query}")
    public List<Map<String,Object>> ShowColumNameAndValue(@PathVariable("Query")String Query) throws SQLException {

      /* MapSqlParameterSource class is intended for passing in a simple Map of parameter values
        to the methods of the {@link NamedParameterJdbcTemplate} class*/

       MapSqlParameterSource msp = new MapSqlParameterSource();

       // this query used for show column name and columnvalues....
        List<Map<String,Object>> css = jdbc.queryForList(Query,msp);

        return css;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //in Service      
      `
                public List<DevicesPerCustomer> findDevicesPerCustomer() {
                    LOGGER.info(TAG_NAME + " :: inside findDevicesPerCustomer : ");
                    List<Object[]> list = iDeviceRegistrationRepo.findDevicesPerCustomer();
                    List<DevicesPerCustomer> out = new ArrayList<>();
                    if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
                        DevicesPerCustomer mDevicesPerCustomer = null;
                        for (Object[] object : list) {
                            mDevicesPerCustomer = new DevicesPerCustomer();
mDevicesPerCustomer.setCustomerId(object[0].toString());
                            mDevicesPerCustomer.setCount(Integer.parseInt(object[1].toString()));
                            
                            out.add(mDevicesPerCustomer);
                        }
                    }
            
                    return out;
                }`
        
    //In Repo
        `   @Query(value = "SELECT d.customerId,count(*) FROM senseer.DEVICE_REGISTRATION d  where d.customerId is not null group by d.customerId", nativeQuery=true)
            List<Object[]> findDevicesPerCustomer();`
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.