# How to implement ORDER BY from a Spring Data JPA GROUP BY query

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Based on question [How to return a custom object from a Spring Data JPA GROUP BY query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36328063/5230740), my custom query is working, as follows:

```
@Query("select new br.com.cwidevs.dto.Goleador(j.id, sum(pj.gols)) from PartidaJogador pj join pj.id.jogador j group by j.id")
public List<Goleador> getGoleadores();
```

Here is the simple bean class:

```
public class Goleador {

    private Long jogador;

    private Long totalGols;    
}
```

At this point, how to implement `ORDER BY`? Can I achieve thi with [Sort](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.sorting)?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Entity
public class Goleador {
    //...
}

@Entity
public class PartidaJogador {
    //...

    @ManyToOne
    private Goleador jogador;

    private Long gols;

    //...
}

// DTO as Projection
public interface GoleadorWithGols {
    Goleador getGoleador();
    Long getTotalGols()
}

public interface GoleadorRepo extends JpaRepository<Goleador, Long> {
    @Query("select j as goleador, sum(pj.gols) as totalGols from PartidaJogador pj join pj.jogador j group by j order by totalGols")
    List<GoleadorWithGols> getGoleadores();
}
```

Here we use a [projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) **GoleadorWithGols** as DTO to get necessary data.

More info is [here](https://spring.io/blog/2016/05/03/what-s-new-in-spring-data-hopper#projections-on-repository-query-methods).

Comment: This solution works, but is hardcoded. Can I receive a Order and set dinamically?

Comment: 'Can I receive a Order and set dinamically?' What do you mean?

Comment: @MurilloGoulart, so what do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

**JpaRepository** extends **PagingAndSortingRepository** so you can definetly use [Sort](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.sorting)

Add parameter to your method
 `public List<Goleador> getGoleadores(Sort sort);` 
when you call it just specify by which column you want to sort your query and you should be good.

```
repoGoleador.getGoleadores(new Sort("jogador"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**I just solved this problem :**

Class-based `Projections` doesn't work with query

```
native(@Query(value = "SELECT ...", nativeQuery = true))
```

So I recommend to define custom `DTO` using interface .
Before using `DTO` should verify the query syntactically correct or not.