# Spring data JPA @Query mapping with named columns

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jdbctemplate

I use Spring Boot 1.5 and spring data JPA with MySQL. I tried to run a simple counting query on a single table, but could not find a better way to map the Query results than this.:

Repository:

```
public interface VehicleRepository extends JpaRepository<Vehicle, String> {
    @Query("select v.sourceModule as sourceModule, count(v) as vehicleCount from Vehicle v group by v.sourceModule")
    List<Object[]> sourceModuleStats();
}
```

Service:

```
@Override
public List<SourceModuleStatDTO> getSourceModuleStats() {
    List<Object[]> objects = vehicleRepository.sourceModuleStats();

    return objects.stream()
            .map(o->SourceModuleStatDTO.from((String)o[0], (Long)o[1]))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I use [org.immutables](https://immutables.github.io/), so the DTO.:

```
@Value.Immutable
@JsonSerialize(as = ImmutableSourceModuleStatDTO.class)
@JsonDeserialize(as = ImmutableSourceModuleStatDTO.class)
public abstract class SourceModuleStatDTO {
    public abstract String sourceModule();
    public abstract long vehicleCount();

    public static SourceModuleStatDTO from(String sm, long c) {
        return ImmutableSourceModuleStatDTO.builder()
                .sourceModule(sm)
                .vehicleCount(c)
                .build();
    }
}
```

The problem here is the mapping, I need to cast the results or manually check everything. Even `JdbcTemplate` has better mapping capabilities, I can't believe there is no better way to do this.

I tried this too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36329166/840315 , but you need to hard code classpaths into the Query to get it work and also I would still need to map the objects to Immutables.

Using JdbcTemplate, you can use the `RowMapper` ([src](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-jdbc-rowmapper-vs-resultsetextractor)) :

```
private static final class EmployeeMapper implements RowMapper<Employee> {
    @Override
    public Employee mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setCountry(rs.getString("country"));
        employee.setEmployeeName(rs.getString("employee"));
        return employee;
    }
}
```

Is there something similar for spring data JPA `@Query`?

Comment: "_simple counting query_" - Are you trying to get _only_ count or count along with sourceModule as well?

Comment: @jusermar10 Count along the `sourceModule`. I know I could use a simple `long` return value if I only wanted the count.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about using [Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) as below?

```
static interface VehicleStats { 
    public String getSourceModule();
    public Long getVehicleCount();
}
```

And your repository method would be

```
@Query("select v.sourceModule as sourceModule, count(v) as vehicleCount from Vehicle v group by v.sourceModule")
List<VehicleStats> sourceModuleStats();
```

In your Service class, you can use the interface methods as below.

```
List<VehicleStats> objects = vehicleRepository.sourceModuleStats();
return objects.stream()
        .map(o->SourceModuleStatDTO.from(getSourceModule(),getVehicleCount() )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you! Maybe it is even easier than using a mapper.

Comment: you saved my day.