# JPARepository & Hibernate return results given ID?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have a one to many relationship between users and tasks (one user has many tasks).

#### Sql:

```
SELECT G.accountability, G.title, G.interval, G.description, U.user_name
FROM user U
LEFT OUTER JOIN GOAL G on (G.USER_ID = U.USER_ID)
```

I insert my data in the database where there is a foreign key association in each task to the user id. Is it possible in JPA to essentially say:

```
Given the user ID here are all the tasks
```

Here is my simple repo

```
import com.habicus.core.model.Goal;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface GoalRepository extends JpaRepository<Goal, Long> {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the tasks using below query which will join the task using the userId.

```
@Query("select task from User user join user.task task where user.id = :userId")
List<Task> getTasksByUserId(@Param("userId") Integer userId)
```

If you want to select specific columns as your query, it would be something like below.

```
@Query("select task.accountability, task.title, task.interval, task.description, user.user_name from User user join user.task task where user.id = :userId")
List<Object[]> getTasksByUserId(@Param("userId") Integer userId)
```

You can as well use Projections if going with second option. Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49094511/5296354) for more details.

Comment: Please make this a full answer, not just a code answer with no explanation.

Comment: @petezurich Added relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your **Goal** and **User** entities are created as follows:

```
@Entity
class User {
   @Id
   private Long id;
   @OneToMany
   private List<Goal> tasks;
   ...
}

@Entity
class Goal {
   @Id
   private Long id;
   @ManyToOne
   private User user;
   ...
}
```

One option is loading user by id and return tasks:

```
userRepository.findById(userId).getTasks()
```

Another option is to add the following method to **GoalRepository**:

```
List<Goal> findByUserId(Long userId);
```

Spring Data JPA strip off **findBy** prefix and build WHERE clause with the rest of the part. So, first, it looks whether there is **userId** property in **Goal**. If not, then it checks for **user** property which in-turn contains **id** property.

PS: Assuming you are referring to goal and task to the same thing.