# How to return a Map of distinct values and their count for a user in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a Spring application and use Spring Data JPA for database manipulation. I have come across a problem with creating a query.

I have a table where users store products. I want to retrieve a Map for a given user, where I will have information about all distinct categories that the given user has his products in, and their count. In native sql that would be the following query :

`SELECT category, count(*) FROM products where user_id = 1 GROUP BY category;`

Can you help me achieving it in a Spring Data Jpa Repository? How should the @Query look like? And how to return the data as a Map?
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49094511/7634201) can help you.

Comment: yes, thanks a lot, that worked fine for me :)