# How to return custom object using projection in Spring Data Jpa?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to return custom object from spring data jpa - **native query**

Here's what I've done so far according to this
[How to return a custom object from a Spring Data JPA GROUP BY query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328063/how-to-return-a-custom-object-from-a-spring-data-jpa-group-by-query)

I should be able to create query like this:

```
Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select sc.case_type as caseType, sc.revision as revision from smart_casemodel sc minus select s.casetype, s.revision from smart_case s")
List<CtRevOnly> findNotUsedCasemodels();
```

I declared projection Interface

```
public interface CtRevOnly {
    String getCaseType();
    String getRevision();
}
```

Then simply call it

```
caseModelRepository.findNotUsedCasemodels();
```

however I get an exception

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity:
>   javax.persistence.Tuple

Any idea what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You need to change your query from SQL query to JPQL query, and make CtRevOnly a class not an interface, check the answer from the link you referred to.

Comment: In accepted answer just below JPQL section is section about native query that's what i am interested in. I know it can be done other ways I am curious about native query and clean code. I would like to make it work using projections. Not mentioned it's harder to change it to JPQL since "minus" is not supported. Offcial documentation using Interfaces as well https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone running into the same problem
I am using Hibernate **5.1.2.Final**

I guess there's a bug and I need to upgrade to hibernate **5.2.11** to make it work
See [this link](https://jira.spring.io/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/DATAJPA-1209/DATAJPA-1209.html)