# Spring Data JPA return wrong totalElement count after group by

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am new to Spring Data JPA and have the something below

```
        Page<Object> page = tableARepository.findAll(
                (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaQuery
                        .where(sortConfig.getPredicateList(root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder))
                        .groupBy(root.get("colB"))
                        .getRestriction(),
                sortConfig.getPageable()
        );
```

Everything is correct except for `page.getTotalElements()` which return the wrong count and I also found out that it is returning the count without `groupBy`.

I need `page.getTotalElements()` in order to show the total rows for front end and currently the workaround was I re-query it and get the size of the result which is not very pretty thing to do (the website still in development stage).

I also did print out the hibernate sql query and the select count query did include `groupBy` but I am not sure what caused it to return the wrong value.

Assume, tableA data as below:

```
ColA  | ColB | ...
1       A
2       B
3       B
4       C
5       D
```

And after `groupBy`
I should have result and count below

```
ColA  | ColB | ...
1       A
2       B
4       C
5       D
```

totalCount: 4

But somehow I got 5, anyone can help?

NOTE: SortConfig is developed by my colleague to use it for pagination purpose.

EDIT:

```
select
    count(tblA_.tableA_ID) as col_0_0_ 
from
    tableA tblA_ 
where
    tblA_.tableAColC like ? 
group by
    tblA_.tableAColB
```

Comment: can u update the question with the hibernate generated sql query

Comment: also what do you mean you have 5 count? can u post the result set that its being returned ? maybe its simple a data issue ?

Comment: @AntJavaDev I did a ```where ColC like abc``` will return 43 rows and 43 count, after that I added a ```groupBy colB``` it will return 33 rows and 43 count.

Comment: ooh now i get your problem !?! cant guess anything else except of those 2 links [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-656)  and [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-945), as a solution i would suggest to use a native query or the original JPA query(not a criteria one) and grab the total count from the result set, not from the pagination element, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55613291/spring-data-jparepository-pagination-and-group-by). Also as a ref from the 2 links, which spring data version are you using?

Comment: @AntJavaDev YES! that's what I am currently facing. So it was a bug and thanks for the links I will check those out. I am using spring data jpa 2.1.10.RELEASE and spring boot 2.1.8.RELEASE.

Answer (score 3):

Use @EnableJpaRepositories to define a repositoryBaseClass, I did it in a config class in a child package.

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableJpaRepositories(
            repositoryBaseClass = SimpleJpaRepositoryEvenForGroupBy.class,
            value = "com.company.repository"
    )
    public class JpaConfig {
    }
```

Write your own executeCountQuery

```java
    /**
     * A SimpleJpaRepository where COUNT returns the right number of rows even for GROUP BY queries.
     */
    public class SimpleJpaRepositoryEvenForGroupBy<T, ID> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> {
    
        public SimpleJpaRepositoryEvenForGroupBy(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
            super(entityInformation, entityManager);
        }
    
        public SimpleJpaRepositoryEvenForGroupBy(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager em) {
            super(domainClass, em);
        }
    
        /**
         * Exactly the same method as in SimpleJpaRepository, but this calls the executeCountQuery of this class
         */
        @Override
        protected <S extends T> Page<S> readPage(TypedQuery<S> query, final Class<S> domainClass, Pageable pageable,
                                                 @Nullable Specification<S> spec) {
    
            if (pageable.isPaged()) {
                query.setFirstResult((int) pageable.getOffset());
                query.setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize());
            }
    
            return PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(query.getResultList(), pageable,
                    () -> executeCountQuery(getCountQuery(spec, domainClass)));
        }
    
        /**
         *  An executeCountQuery where COUNT returns the right number of rows even for GROUP BY queries.
         */
        private static long executeCountQuery(TypedQuery<Long> query) {
            Assert.notNull(query, "TypedQuery must not be null!");
    
            List<Long> resultList = query.getResultList();
            if (resultList.size() == 1) {
                return resultList.get(0);
            }
    
            return resultList.size();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is confirmed that it was a bug in Pageable based on @AntJavaDev commments.

For now I changed to use PageImpl approach that found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37749559/conversion-of-list-to-page-in-spring) and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Check your pageable object if it indexes from zero. Something like:

```
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(pageId-1, size);
```

Comment: Check the implementation of sortConfig. That is where the problem is. If you can paste the part of the class that has to do with pagination.