# How to return a List of Objects instead of Array of Objects from a Spring Data JPA GROUP BY query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, repository

My question is related to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328063/how-to-return-a-custom-object-from-a-spring-data-jpa-group-by-query).

Following is my repository method using group by some field:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT  t.test_id AS testId, COUNT(t.id) AS total FROM test_instances t GROUP BY t.test_id", nativeQuery = true)
public Object[] getTestStats();
```

It's working and the result is obtained as follows:

```
[ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 3, 2 ], [ 5, 1 ], [ 7, 2 ], [ 8, 1 ], [ 9, 1 ] ]
```

But, when I replace return type of getTestStats() from `Object[]` to `List<?>` I am getting the following error message:

```
{
"cause": null,
"message": "Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class [Ljava.lang.Object;!"]
}
```

I want to use `List<?>` because if it is working, I want to use custom projection to cast it to i.e., `List<CustomProjection>`

I tried following return types `{List<?>, List<CustomProjection>, CustomProjection[]}`; 
but every thing is returning the same error. Hope someone will help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return a List then :

1. create a constructor which hold this fiels
2. in your query you can create an Object which took this fields.

For example :

```
 Select new com.CustomObject(t.test_id, COUNT(t.id))
```

And in this case you can use `List<CustomObject>` instead of an array of objects

Comment: I tried this also but still, it causes the same error. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If I return only one record from the query using where clause then I can easily map that record to the CustomObject, but I am unable to do it while returning multiple records.

Comment: This is a general solution, can you confirm that you example is the same as your real code?

Comment: Yes, this is my real code, I just copied it and pasted. please help me, I am struck with it.

Comment: Can you please show me your code after edit ? And which version of spring boot you are using?

Comment: My spring boot version: "2.1.8.RELEASE" and hibernate version: "5.3.11.Final" and STS version : "4.4.0.RELEASE"

Comment: it should be public ```Object[][] getTestStats()```

Comment: @MohanMunisifreddy please show me your code after edit

Comment: @EmmanuelOgoma do you mean List<CustomProjection[]> will work? I tried it, but no use.

Comment: @YCF_L    @Query("SELECT  new com.xxx.xxx.TestInstanceStats(t.testId, COUNT(t.id)) FROM TestInstance t GROUP BY t.testId")
public List<TestInstanceStats> getTestStats();  ---> If I replace List<TestInstanceStats> with Object[] then it is working but I want to return it as TestInstanceStats

Comment: @MohanMunisifreddy do you create a constructor in your class which how the id and Lond attribute as count?

Comment: Ya, I created constructor with the same attributes.

Comment: @YCF_L when I change the query to return only one record and map it to TestInstanceStats it is working i.e., public TestInstanceStats getTestStats(); but I am unable to return the list of projections