# JPA Repository Join With Child Entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

Let's say I have these two entities:

**Book.java**

```java
@Entity
public class Book {
  public Integer id;
  public Integer authorId;
  public String title;
}
```

**Author.java**

```java
@Entity
public class Author {
  public Integer id;
  public String firstName;
  public String lastName;
}
```

How can I query all the books, along with their author? Something like

```java
public interface BookRepository implements JpaRepository<Book, Integer> {
  @Query("FROM Book b JOIN FETCH Author a ON b.authorId = a.id")
  List<BookWithAuthor> findAllWithAuthor();
}
```

Where `BookWithAuthor` is the following:

```java
public class BookWithAuthor {
  public Integer id;
  public String title;
  public Author author;
}
```

So far, I've done some research, and came across these solutions (which do not suit me):

- [Solution 1](https://learningprogramming.net/java/spring-boot-jpa/join-in-custom-query-in-spring-boot-jpa) ("ProductRepository Interface"): you need to enter the full package name and call a constructor
- [Solution 2](https://medium.com/@techkarmo/spring-data-jpa-join-with-unrelated-entities-with-help-of-jpql-in-spring-boot-application-c358e11512bd): it uses the EntityManager, which I don't want.

How can I achieve my goal?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use a native query as well. See accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328063/how-to-return-a-custom-object-from-a-spring-data-jpa-group-by-query)

Comment: Your book and author class are not even defined as entities, so it is hard to answer.
In general you should have a look at OneToOne-Relationships and can then either work with eager-loading or entity-graphs.

Comment: @Seb You're right, I just forgot to add these annotations, thanks!

Comment: In your entity classes there is no relationship between two entities.

Comment: @ray You're right, I've manually defined the relations in the DBMS to keep the entities simple. Should I use a `@OneToMany` relationship in all cases?

Comment: Yes without relationship no data

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Okay, I'm gonna use relations then. I'll post the resulting code as the answer to this question. Thanks :)