# how to change type of return with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

how to change type of return?
I tried doing this but it doesn't work. How can I do it correctly ?

current response :

```
[
    [
        1,
        "ADMIN",
        "ADMIN"
    ],
    [
        1,
        "Ali",
        "RE"
    ],
    [
        2,
        "Sami",
        "AZ"
    ],
]
```

i want to sent request like below postman

```
[
    [
       "nbrResponsable": 1,
       "nom_personnel":"ADMIN",
       "prenom_personnel":"ADMIN"
   ]
       "nbrResponsable": 1,
       "nom_personnel":"Ali",
       "prenom_personnel":"RE"
   ],
]
```

Repository:

```
@Query(value ="SELECT count(pe.personnel_id)nbrResponsable, pe.prenom_personnel,pe.nom_personnel " +
        "             FROM personnel pe " +
        "join  action_securisation ac on   pe.personnel_id = ac.responsable_action_securisation_id " +
        "group by pe.prenom_personnel,pe.nom_personnel " , nativeQuery = true)
List ResponsableActionCorrective();
```

Service:

```
public List ResponsableActionCorrectiveByPeriod() {
    List ListeActionCorrective ;
       ListeActionCorrective=listeActionCorrectiveRepository.ResponsableActionCorrective();
    return ListeActionCorrective;
}
```

Controller :

```
   @GetMapping("/responsableActionCorrectiveByPeriod")
        public List ResponsableActionCorrectiveByPeriod() {
            return listeActionCorrectiveService.ResponsableActionCorrectiveByPeriod();
        }
```

Comment: Could you please add your current request/response and expected request/response

Comment: Thanks for the pointer I simply had to change my list from List<Map<String,Object>>

Comment: @amer if you solved your issue already, please add the solution as an answer and accept it as the correct one. Thanks.

Comment: this might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36329166/4274223

Answer (score 2):

You should use Maps instead of a Lists to return as objects.

```java
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("nbrResponsable", "1");
map.put("nom_personnel", "ADMIN");
map.put("prenom_personnel", "ADMIN");
```