# How to get non related entity using JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities

```
@Entity
public class Language {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

private String name;

private String isoCode;

}
```

and the another entity

```
@Entity
public class MainEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

private String anotherField;

private Language language;  //(here I want to return the full entity)

}
```

The entities don't have a database relation just a string field, Now I want to do a query for MainEntity but I want to get the full entity

For example

Language

|  | value |
| --- | --- |
| id | 1 |
| name | English |
| isoCode | EN |

MainEntity

|  | value |
| --- | --- |
| id | a |
| name | xyz |
| language | EN |

I have that repository

```
public interface MainRepository extends JpaRepository<MainEntity, Integer>{

User findAll();
}
```

but I want that when I do a search on my primary entity it brings me the entire language entity

for example

MyEntity.Language.getName()

Comment: Why are you not making the entities in relation? You have some special constraint?

Answer (score 0):

Use native query to read JPA objects? See this simplified example where you can use any valid native sql query syntax.

You could put `Language getLanguage()` function to MainEntity class.

```
String sql = "Select * From MyEntityTable Where id between (?1 and ?2)";
Query query = entityMgr.createNativeQuery(sql, MyEntity.class);
query.setParameter(1, 1001);
query.setParameter(2, 2002);
List<MyEntity> list = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: How do you retrive the name of the language like this? Also you can perform a native query with `@Query("....", native=true)`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make a reletion between `MainEntity` and `Language` you have to make a native query. (As is you can't make also a jpql query because you should have at least the `String language` in the `MainEntity` in order to make a join on `String isoCode` in `Language` but as I understand I think you don't want to do that).
So you have to perform a native query returning an interface as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328063/how-to-return-a-custom-object-from-a-spring-data-jpa-group-by-query)

```
public interface IntermediateObject {
    int getId();

    String getName();

    int getLanguageId();

    String getLanguageName();

    String getIsoCode();
}
```

In the repository:

```
@Query("select m.id as id, m.name as name, l.id as languageId, l.name as languageName, l.isoCode as isoCode MainEntity m join Language l on m.language = l.isoCode", native=true)
List<IntermediateObject> someMethod();
```

In the MainEntity or better another dto you have to declare a constructor:

```
public class AnotherDto {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private LanguageDto language;

    public AnotherDto(int id, String name, int languageId, String languageName, String isoCOde) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.language = new LanguageDto(languageId, languageName, isoCode);
    }

}
public class LanguageDto {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String isoCode;

    public LanguageDto(int id, String name, String isoCode) {
        this.id;
        this.name = name;
        this.isoCode = isoCode;
    }
}
```

And in the service layer you have to construct `AnotherDto` from `IntermediateObject`

```
public List<AnotherDto> someMethod() {
    return repository.someMethod().stream().map(i -> new AnotherDto(i.getId(), i.getName(), i.getLanguageId(), i.getLanguageName(), i.getIsoCode())).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

and now you have the language object populated.

Anyway I suggest to map the entities instead to do all of this.